# The complex version of the chain rule

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to prove the following equality:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} (g \circ f) = (\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}) + (\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar{z}} \frac{\partial \bar{f}}{\partial z})
\end{eqnarray}

So I decide to do the following:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial}{\partial z} (g \circ f) = \frac{1}{2}[(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \circ f)(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}) + \frac{1}{i}(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \circ f)(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})]
\end{eqnarray}

but the thing is that I am doing something wrong here since I don't get any conjugate function and any derivative with respect to $\bar{z}$ so Can someone help me to see where I am wrong and fix it please?

In fact I don't see what to do next, so I appreciate your help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

> **Edition:**

What I've got so far is the following:

$$\frac{1}{2}[(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \circ f + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \circ f)\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} ]$$

but I'm still stuck.

Comment: Note that $\frac 1i=-i$

Comment: Right, but what continues after my calculations? is because I don't see what to do next :)

Comment: If you think $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$ and compute the chain rule for functions in two real variables, you see that it is very easy... Maybe a lot of calculations but easy... In coordinates $(z, \bar z)$, the Cauchy-Riemann equations imply that the derivatives are diagonal matrices.

Comment: Can you elaborate more please ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is taken in the context of [Wirtinger Derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives).

To that end, we let $g$ and $f$ be functions of both $z$ and $\bar z$.  Then, the composite function $g\circ f$ can be expressed as

$$g\circ f=g(f(z,\bar z),\bar f(z,\bar z))$$

The partial derivative of $g\circ f$ with respect to $z$ is then given by

$$\begin{align}
\frac{\partial (g\circ f)}{\partial z}&=\frac{\partial (g(f(z,\bar z),\bar f(z,\bar z))}{\partial z}\\\\
&=\left.\frac{\partial g(w,\bar w)}{\partial w}\right|_{w=f(z,\bar z)}\times \frac{\partial f(z,\bar z)}{\partial z}+\left.\frac{\partial g(w,\bar w)}{\partial \bar w}\right|_{\bar w=\bar f(z,\bar z)}\times \frac{\partial \bar f(z,\bar z)}{\partial z}\\\\
&=\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\circ f\right)\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}+\left(\frac{\partial g}{\partial \bar z}\circ f\right)\frac{\partial \bar f}{\partial z}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Why do we have 2 complex variables ?

Comment: @user162343 Here, we have one complex variable, namely $z$.  But the functions $f$ and $g$ can be functions of both $z$ and its complex conjugate $\bar z$.

Comment: I have seen this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490863/homework-problem-complex-analysis-chain-rule?rq=1 but can you explain me the substitutions he did for $dg,d \bar{z},...$ is because I can't figure out how is that possible :) Thanks.

Comment: Then, what do you think about the comment above?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Please help me understand.  Perhaps the new question should be posted as such.  ;-))

Comment: Oh :), well the thing is that in above link is in fact the result, the thing is that I don't understand how he made the calculations :) Thanks for replying.

Comment: Well in fact I understand your answer :), but with $\times$ you mean multiplication right?

Comment: Yes, the $\times$ symbol is multiplication and not $x$.

Comment: @MarkViola Sir  I had doubt that ,How you have written last step? THat is w tern to z.Please tell me

Comment: @MathLover Hi. Note that $w$ is a "dummy" variable.

Comment: @MarkViola I was also stuck on this. I didn't think of writing $g\circ f=g(f(z,\bar z),\bar f(z,\bar z))$. That helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: How does $\partial w$ become $\partial z$ in the last step?

Comment: @Abel $g(z,\bar z)$.

Answer (score 5):

You do some mistakes. Note that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (g \circ f) = (\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \circ f)(\operatorname{Re}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})+(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \circ f)(\operatorname{Im}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})$$ and $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} (g \circ f) = (\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} \circ f)(\operatorname{Re}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y})+(\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \circ f)(\operatorname{Im}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}).$$ Now you should be able to finish your calculations.

Comment: Ok, Let me try if I got questions Can I let you know ?

Comment: Yes of course :)

Comment: I've edited my post :)

Comment: I have seen this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/490863/homework-problem-complex-analysis-chain-rule?rq=1 but can you explain me the substitutions he did for $dg,d \bar{z},...$ is because I can't figure out how is that possible :) Thanks.

Comment: Then, what do you think about my calculations and the comment above?

Answer (score 3):

Define $z=x+iy$, then$$\begin{cases}
   x=\frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}\\
   y=\frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}
  \end{cases}.$$ We consider $x$ and $y$ are functions of $z$ and $\overline{z}$, thus we have
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right) ;\quad \frac{\partial }{\partial \overline{z}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-\frac{1}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \right)$$which shows $z$ is exactly what we have already known. We consider $h$, $f$, $g$ all are the functions of $z$ and $\overline{z}$, then we have$$dh=\frac{\partial h}{\partial z}dz+\frac{\partial h}{\partial \overline{z}}d\overline{z}.$$Also we can express$g\circ f$ as
$$g\circ f=g(f(z,\overline{z}),\overline{f}(z,\overline{z})).$$Then,$$d(g\circ f)=\left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial\overline{z}}\frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial z}\right)dz+
 \left( \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z}}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial\overline{z}}\frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial \overline{z}}\right)d\overline{z}. $$Compared with $dh$ and $d(g\circ f)$, the complex version of chain rule is proved.

Comment: Can you explain why
$\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} \ =\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} +\frac{\partial g}{\partial \overline{z}}\frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial z}$
and not
$\frac{\partial h}{\partial z} \ =\ \frac{\partial g}{\partial f}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} +\frac{\partial g}{\partial \overline{f}}\frac{\partial \overline{f}}{\partial z}$?
And the same for the second part.
I can't derive or find the identity

Comment: @biogrisha Sorry, I can't remember the details in complex analysis, while I suppose you should try to figure out the actual meaning behind those notations of derivatives, as they are just some symbols.